# Resolve "Cannot find package" error using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to import a module using Node.js. When I specify the path I'm importing from, it works perfectly fine. Code below runs without returning any error

```
import myFunc from("./lib/myPkg.js");
import pkg from ("root/node_modules/date-names/index.js");
const {days, months} = pkg;
```

However, I get this error when I try to import an npm package by calling `import ordinal from "ordinal"`

```
root@username:/path/to/main.mjs# node main.mjs
internal/process/esm_loader.js:74
    internalBinding('errors').triggerUncaughtException(
                              ^

Error [ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND]: Cannot find package 'ordinal' imported from /path/to/main.mjs
    at packageResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:675:9)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:716:14)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:809:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:229:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:51:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:50:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

I have tried installing the package globally but I still can't get it to work.

Comment: Can you share your package.json?

Comment: I have the default package.json for ordinal when I installed it using `npm install ordinal`